# How to set tab for zsh autocompletion?

Tags: shell, unix, autocomplete, zsh

I want to set tab for zsh autocomplition plugin. There is related part of config:

```
# Widgets that accept the entire suggestion
(( ! ${+ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS} )) && {
        typeset -ga ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS
        ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_ACCEPT_WIDGETS=(
                forward-char
                end-of-line
                tab-char //my line
                vi-forward-char
                vi-end-of-line
                vi-add-eol
        )
}
```

What is the convention for char names used?
How does tab named?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will have to put

```
bindkey '       ' autosuggest-accept
```

into your `.zshrc` file. Notice that the space between the apostrophe is one keystroke of the tab-character.
This works similarly with every other character or character combination. If you for example wanted to put a combination of the `ctrl`+`space` keys to trigger the acception, you'd append

```
bindkey '^ ' autosuggest-accept
```

to the file.

Here's a link to the Configuration-file, where this is explained: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions#key-bindings

Comment: and how to bind tab?

Comment: I think you have one more space or something, I have copy pasted and it wasn't working.
The best way is to directly type `bindkey '' autosuggest-accept` and then place the cursor in between the tick and press `tab`.

Comment: Note that typically modern editors are set to expand the `tab` key to spaces, which would prevent this from working.

Answer (score 28):

For all of you that are struggling with the accepted answer, I got it to work doing the following:

```
bindkey '^I' autosuggest-accept
```

...where '^I' is tab.

Comment: This worked for me. +1.

Comment: I guess it's showing `^I` because you are using vim and used `:set list`

Comment: on Mac M1, I needed to do `bindkey '^I' expand-or-complete`

Answer (score 12):

In the `.zshrc` file:

```
bindkey '^I'   complete-word       # tab          | complete
bindkey '^[[Z' autosuggest-accept  # shift + tab  | autosuggest
```

https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/532#issuecomment-907361899

Comment: complete-word works for me. Thanks!

Comment: This is great. Works on Mac and is exactly the right combination to use zsh-autocomplete and zsh-autosuggestions together.

Answer (score 7):

this seems to work as expected in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
bindkey '\t' autosuggest-accept
```

If you want to know more, you can [click here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/issues/532)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. On Ubuntu 22LTS, Gnome and VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a bit old, but leaving it here for those who try to use this later.

What I am using is

```
bindkey '^I^I' autosuggest-accept
```

If I press tab key twice in succession, it completes the command. If I tap tab once and leave I can use the shell's suggestions and cycle through them.